# Angular 4 : After setting height to the nav bar the toggle button not expand the menu in bootstrap 4

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I am working in an angular app ,here as per the business I need to change the nav bar height using style properties and it's worked .

But in my case when I minimized the screen the toggle button is not opening the menus .

Here I have attached the stackblitz file :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wbecxm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Can anyone help me to fix it

Comment: what is the issue the current stackblitz example working fine

Comment: Nav menu width is not matching the toggle menu witdth after click on toggle button  @Chellappan

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes in your HTML structure. 
Try adding following styles as well as changing the HTML structure:

```css
.navbar {
  padding: 0.25rem 1rem;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
  width: 0.9em;
  height: 0.9em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class=" navbar  navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <div class="container">
    <img style="outline: none;cursor: pointer;" src="assets/Images/Logo/home.png" routerLink="/landingpage" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item" style="margin-left: 20px">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/landingpage" style="color: #FFFFFF">Demo 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" style="margin-left: 20px;cursor: pointer;">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle " href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color: #FFFFFF">
            Demo 2
          </a>

          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                Hi
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </li>
        <li class="nav-item " style="margin-left: 20px">
          <a class="nav-link " style="color: #FFFFFF" routerLink="/contactus">Demo 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```